# How to test existence of properties on object

Tags: coffeescript

Given something like:

```
@props.field1.field2.field3
```

I want to test if field3 exists. So:

```
@props.field1.field2.field3?
```

But. If field2 does not exist on field1 then then above line produces an error.

But I want to avoid a bunch of nested tests:

```
if @props.field1
  if @props.field2
   if @props.field3
     //do something
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#operators):

> **The Existential Operator**
>   [...]
>   The accessor variant of the existential operator `?.` can be used to soak up null references in a chain of properties. Use it instead of the dot accessor `.` in cases where the base value may be **null** or **undefined**. If all of the properties exist then you'll get the expected result, if the chain is broken, **undefined** is returned instead of the **TypeError** that would be raised otherwise.

So you could say:

```
@props?.field1?.field2?.field3?
```

to ignore missing properties all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

```
if @props.field1 && @props.field2 && @props.field3
```

If one of the properties does not exists the compiler will not test any of the following

Actually
`if @props.field3` should do the job